# How can I log Inno Setup installations?

Tags: logging, inno-setup

Inno Setup has command line parameter `/LOG="filename"`. Can I specify a log filename from inside the Inno Setup script, so I can include it later in my error reports?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the `SetupLogging` option (`SetupLogging=yes`) then integrate the following code into your script to copy the log somewhere.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  logfilepathname, logfilename, newfilepathname: string;
begin
  logfilepathname := ExpandConstant('{log}');
  logfilename := ExtractFileName(logfilepathname);
  newfilepathname := ExpandConstant('{app}\') + logfilename;

  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    FileCopy(logfilepathname, newfilepathname, false);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you really think it's necessary to recalculate the paths and file names again and again for every setup step? Why not move that into the `if CurStep = ssDone then`-block?

Comment: +1 Mittheil! I've used your tip but call in DeinitializeSetup instead. Then the log is copied even if the user exits Setup before anything is installed.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Is it possible to add my own lines to the installation log?

Comment: @JConstantine See [How to log [file copying process\] in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34634167/850848)

Answer (score 16):

Following the comment from Lars I used the `DeinitializeSetup()` procedure, but I also changed the new file path to use the `{src}` constant to copy the log file to the directory that the installer is run from instead of `{app}` constant which may/may not be created if the user cancels the installation:

```pascal
// Called just before Setup terminates. Note that this function is called even if the user exits Setup before anything is installed.
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
var
  logfilepathname, logfilename, newfilepathname: string;
begin
  logfilepathname := ExpandConstant('{log}');
  logfilename := ExtractFileName(logfilepathname);
  // Set the new target path as the directory where the installer is being run from
  newfilepathname := ExpandConstant('{src}\') + logfilename;

  FileCopy(logfilepathname, newfilepathname, false);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the example from JasonMcF... checking if the uninstaller was created to see if the setup was finished successfully.

```
// Called just before Setup terminates.
// Note that this function is called even if the user exits Setup before anything is installed.
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
var
    unInstaller, logFilePath, logFileName, newFilePath: string;
begin
    unInstaller := ExpandConstant('{uninstallexe}');

    logFilePath := ExpandConstant('{log}');
    logFileName := ExtractFileName(logFilePath);
  
    if FileExists(unInstaller) then
    begin
        // uninstaller exists, setup was finished successfully, copy log to app directory
        newFilePath := ExpandConstant('{app}\') + logFileName;
    end
        else
    begin
        // setup didn't finish successfully, copy log to src directory
        newFilePath := ExpandConstant('{src}\') + logFileName;
    end;

    Log('DeinitializeSetup');
    Log('- unInstaller:' + unInstaller);
    Log('- logFilePath:' + logFilePath);
    Log('- newFilePath:' + newFilePath);

    FileCopy(logFilePath, newFilePath, false);
end;
```

Comment: For checking if installation succeeded or not, see [How to call an exe when Inno Setup installation fails (within the installer itself)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33343283/850848)