# Inno Setup : multiple issues with logging in the script

Tags: logging, inno-setup

Friends, I'm facing two issues with logging in my inno script.

I'm using the first solution specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116217/how-can-i-log-inno-setup-installations) to set up logging in my script.

First, I have a log right at the start of a function IsJRE64 which is called as shown here-

```
[Files]
Source: ".\win32\rxtxSerial.dll"; DestDir: "{code:GetJREpath}\bin\"; Check: not IsJRE64 
Source: ".\win64\rxtxSerial.dll"; DestDir: "{code:GetJREpath}\bin\"; Check: IsJRE64
```

In my log file, I see multiple (running into 100's) entries of this log. Couldn't fathom why. Any pointers ?

Second, I'm adding a registry entry as

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ABC"; ValueData: """{app}\LD\Installers\TomcatService.bat"""
```

I need to be able to add an entry into the log file specifying whether the write to registry was successful or not. How is that possible with this statement ?

Please help by sharing your views/opinions on what I need to do to resolve these.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: You can use the `AfterInstall` parameter.

Comment: Thanks TLama.....totally missed that !!

Comment: Any ideas on why I'm seeing multiple log entries though ?