# How to call an exe when Inno Setup installation fails (within the installer itself)?

Tags: inno-setup, exit-code, pascalscript

I've been using Inno Setup for several months now, but I'm struggling to find how to detect, from within the installer itself, an error that would cause Inno Setup to end with a non-zero exit code.

I've thought about using `CurStepChanged` with the `ssDone` step, or even `DeinitializeSetup`, but I can't find how to get access to the wizard's exit-code.

Did I miss something? There must be a way to do it...

I'd like to know if anything went wrong so that I can start a rollback procedure on the machine. Your proposed answer did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot find out installer exit code from the Pascal Scripting.

---

If you want to detect that the installer failed, remember if `CurStepChanged` was called with `ssDone` and test that in `DeinitializeSetup`.

```pascal
var
  Succeeded: Boolean;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  if Succeeded then
  begin
    Log('Installation succeeded');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Installation failed');
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    Succeeded := True;
  end;
end;
```

---

There are edge cases, when `ssDone` is used even, if the installer fails.

For example, when it fails because a machine was not restarted to complete the previous installation. In this case the `CurStepChanged` is not called with `ssPostInstall`. So you may want to check for both steps, if this scenario can happen in your installer.

Comment: Ok so I hacked around with your solution and it now works as intended. Thanks a lot.