# Detecting that installation was aborted/cancelled in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup installer with some code in the `DeinitilizeSetup()` procedure. Importantly, this procedure includes calls to create/start a service (that it just installed) that hosts a localhost REST API, and then calls to that API to 'finish' the install (that's sort of a misleading name, but that's not important).

Here's the deal: If the installation aborted for any reason (current test case is if the application was open, so the installer couldn't overwrite the exe/etc), it aborts because it's running in `/verysilent` mode. But I want to KNOW that it is aborting (vs a happy path ending) and call the RESTAPI with a querystring parameter as true vs false.

I'm all set with a conditional like this:

```pascal
if (InstallerCanceled = true) then begin
    Log('Calling Service''s FinishInstall endpoint with errorOccurred=true')
    WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/api/update/FinishInstall?errorOccurred=true', False)
  end
  else begin
    Log('Calling Service''s FinishInstall endpoint with errorOccurred=false');
    WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/api/update/FinishInstall?errorOccurred=false', False);
  end
WinHttpReq.Send('');
```

But I can't figure out how to define the conditional itself...how do I know if the install was cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `ssDone` in [`CurStepChanged` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

To distinguish if installation was canceled or aborted, test if [`CancelButtonClick` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CancelButtonClick) was triggered.

For similar questions, see:

- [Inno Setup - How to display a message after installation is cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40982671/850848)
- [How to call an exe when Inno Setup installation fails (within the installer itself)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33343283/850848)
- [Is there a way to known InnoSetup installation abort/failure reason within Inno Setup Pascal script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76090304/850848)

Comment: @Niki If you have a question, please [post a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with all details you have. Why do you need that? What would it be good for?

Comment: Here is the quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090304/is-there-a-way-to-known-innosetup-installation-abort-failure-reason-within-delph