# How to log file copying process in Inno Setup

Tags: logging, installation, inno-setup

During the installation, I need to copy some files from folder to another, how can I be sure, that this copying process was successful?

```pascall
FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{src}\copy.txt'), ExpandConstant('{app}\test_success.txt'), false);
```

Is there any possibility to log copying process during installation.

`SetupLogging` does not provide any information about copying process during the installation

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Log` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_log):

```pascal
function FileCopyLogged(
  const ExistingFile, NewFile: String; const FailIfExists: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileCopy(ExistingFile, NewFile, FailIfExists);
  if Result then
  begin
    Log(Format('Copying %s to %s succeeded', [ExistingFile, NewFile]));
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Copying %s to %s failed', [ExistingFile, NewFile]));
  end;
end;
```

Use the `FileCopyLogged` the same way you are using `FileCopy`:

```pascal
FileCopyLogged(
  ExpandConstant('{src}\copy.txt'), ExpandConstant('{app}\test_success.txt'), false);
```