# Run installation using Inno Setup silently without any Next button or Install button

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want my installation should be silent without any *Next* or *Install* buttons clicked by the user. I tried to disable all pages still, I am getting the *"Ready to Install"* page. I want avoid this install page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run an installer built in Inno Setup without any interaction with the user or even without any window, use the [`/SILENT` or `/VERYSILENT` command-line parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline):

> Instructs Setup to be silent or very silent. When Setup is silent the wizard and the background window are not displayed but the installation progress window is. When a setup is very silent this installation progress window is not displayed. Everything else is normal so for example error messages during installation are displayed and the startup prompt is (if you haven't disabled it with DisableStartupPrompt or the '/SP-' command line option explained above).

---

You may also consider using the `/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES` parameter.

---

If you want to make your installer run "silently" without any additional command-line switches *(what is imo very wrong approach)*, you can:

- Use the [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) to skip most pages.
- Use a timer to skip the "Ready to Install" page (which cannot be skipped using the `ShouldSkipPage`). You can use the technique shown in [How to close finished Inno Setup installer after a certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42391190/850848)

```pascal
[Code]

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

function SetTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent, uElapse, lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@User32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'KillTimer@User32.dll stdcall';

var
  SubmitPageTimer: LongWord;

procedure KillSubmitPageTimer;
begin
  KillTimer(0, SubmitPageTimer);
  SubmitPageTimer := 0;
end;  

procedure SubmitPageProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(WizardForm.NextButton);
  KillSubmitPageTimer;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    SubmitPageTimer := SetTimer(0, 0, 100, CreateCallback(@SubmitPageProc));
  end
    else
  begin
    if SubmitPageTimer <> 0 then
    begin
      KillSubmitPageTimer;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

Another approach is to send `CN_COMMAND` to the *Next* button, as shown here: [How to skip all the wizard pages and go directly to the installation process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22183811/850848)

---

Another option (with its own caveats) is respawning the installer with the `/[VERY]SILENT` switch. You can use the technique described here:
[Inno Setup specify log name within the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35803732/850848)

---

For a similar question with different answers, see [How to make the silent installation by using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21575241/850848)