# How to force using /NORESTART and other flags without using command line

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to force using some flags like `/NORESTART`, `/NOCLOSEAPPLICATIONS` or `/VERYSILENT` in Inno Setup without using command line?

Answer (score 0):

*There's no generic solution to your question that would cover all switches. Implementing a functionality of each switch needs an ad-hoc implementation (and hence requires a separate question).*

*Actually, you can use .inf file instead of the command-line. But I assume that this not what you ask for.*

*`/VERYSILENT` is answered here already:

[Run installation using Inno Setup silently without any Next button or Install button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42089779/850848)*.

*I'm answering the `/NORESTART` switch here.*

---

You can hide Yes/No restart radio buttons (and select the No). And update the screen text accordingly.

See [Avoid restart prompt in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63424813/850848).

Additional handling is needed if you have `postinstall` entries in the `[Run]` section.