# Avoid restart prompt in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using `restartreplace` flag to replace the locked file, so it will prompt a message at the end of the installation to restart the machine. But I don't want to display it, and it should be set to restart later by default. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide Yes/No restart radio buttons. And update the screen text accordingly.

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  S: string;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    WizardForm.YesRadio.Visible := False;
    WizardForm.NoRadio.Visible := False;
    WizardForm.NoRadio.Checked := True;
    S := SetupMessage(msgFinishedLabelNoIcons);
    StringChangeEx(S, '[name]', 'My Program', True);
    WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption := S;
    WizardForm.AdjustLabelHeight(WizardForm.FinishedLabel);
  end; 
end;
```