# Making an Inno Setup installation run silently by default

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup has a `/VERYSILENT` option, which suppresses wizard and progress windows. I would like this behavior to be the default when the executable is run without parameters.

Is there a way to achieve this using directives in the `Setup` section, preprocessor tricks or other clever methods? I'm aware of directives such as `DisableStartupPrompt` that disable specific wizard pages; my goal is to be VERY silent. :-)

Comment: For a start, see [Run installation using Inno Setup silently without any Next button or Install button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42089779/850848). You definitely should not make an a "very silent" installer. If your aim was to replace the GUI with your own, you might try doing what the previously linked question shows plus hiding the wizard window (`WizardForm.Hide`). Though you might as well just modify the wizard window to look like you want.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, the goal is to not have a GUI at all. Thanks for the hint; I will have a look at your link.

Comment: Why would you want o do that? It smacks of a virus that you want to execute on a persons PC without them realizing ...

Comment: @AndrewTruckle though I don't doubt that is one malevolent use case, I have customers with an identical benign requirement: they need to run installers in an automated fashion. Its not so much the visibility of a GUI that is actually the problem for them, but that any GUI dependency on a user interaction would make automation impossible. And unwanted user interaction could actually cause problems.

Comment: @StayOnTarget For intended automated use, there's the `/VERYSILENT`.

Comment: Benevolent intent in a design doesn't stop bad actors from abusing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "no." Inno Setup is an installer builder that requires a specific request from the user via the command line (`/silent`, `/verysilent`) to run a hands-free installation. This is by design.